# Biber, TeX Live 2013, and OS X 10.9

Tags: biber, filecontents

This question is related to the question [Tufte-Style Asides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146255/tufte-style-asides).

I downloaded `caesar_example.tex` from [Github sources](https://github.com/andythomas/TeX-sidenotes) and complied it from TeXShop. The output file `caesar_example.pdf` does not contain the bibliography.  After examining the console I identified the following as a possible problem.

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 126.

[7] (./caesar_example.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:

(biblatex)                caesar_example

(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

I was wondering if the `biber` package is not installed in my TeX Live 2013. So, I included the line `\usepackage{biber}` and re-compiled the modified `caesar_example.tex` file. Then there was no compilation and I got the following message on the console.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `biber.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,

or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

Then I used "TeX Live Utility" to see if this is true. I found out that the following `biber` packages are installed.

`universal-da universal darwin files of biber`

`x86_64-darwin x86_64-darwin files of biber`

What do I have to do to get `caesar_example.tex` properly compiled?

(If this question is too localized then is there a place that I can ask this question?)

Comment: You need to run biber (instead of bibtex). If texshop has no menu for biber than replace in the configuration bibtex by biber and then use the bibtex menu.

Comment: Wasted a lot of time on this.  Even tried [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38348/in-texshop-is-there-a-directive-to-select-biber-or-bibtex-on-a-per-document-bas).  Time to give up?

Comment: Finally I figured it out. I think the link [ME/AM](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38348/in-texshop-is-there-a-directive-to-select-biber-or-bibtex-on-a-per-document-bas) helped.  I compiled the file with the option `BibTex` chosen instead of `LaTeX`.

Comment: Ulrike already gave the answer, why would you give up? I uploaded a new version of `caesar_example.tex` on Github that includes the biber directive when using TeXShop>3.21. A more descriptive answer is given [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125712/8631). It might be good to vote that answer up.